# print (alert) className of link javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

how to i "print" aka alert the class name of the link when I click that link?

(just parts of the code)

html

```
<div id="more"><a href="javascript:more();" class="class3">more</a></div>
```

---

javascript

```
    function more()
{
window.alert(document.getElementById("more").getElementsByTagName("a").className);
}
```

what am I doing wrong? Because this isn't working.

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByTagName will return an array

```
function more()
{
    window.alert(document.getElementById("more").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className);
}
```

className property is available for items inside that array.

Comment: It returns a `NodeList`, not an array.

Comment: Sorry used the wrong term. Main concern is that it is a list of items so it should be treated like that.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` will return an `NodeList` so access [0]th Element to get a name
Try this

```
function more()
{
var name = document.getElementById('more').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].className;
console.log(name);
alert(name);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wzEgh/)

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a (Node)list of elements, even if there is just one or no match. So use following:

```
function more()
{
window.alert(document.getElementById("more").getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className);
}
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dhpx9/